# track facebook event IOS 14.5+ react-native-fbsdk-next

Tags: react-native, facebook, react-native-fbsdk

I want to track event in IOS14.5 and higher, I ask the user for permission to track events and send it to facebook

`

```
const trackingStatus = yield getTrackingStatus();

if (trackingStatus === 'authorized' || trackingStatus === 'unavailable') {

   Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true);

} else Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(false);`
```

and facebook see this permission [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZe8O.png)

then I track event like this

```
export default function trackEvent(name = '', params = {}): void {
const eventParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params));
analytics().logEvent(name, { params: eventParams });

 if (name !== 'start_trial' && name !== 'purchase_confirmed') {
   AppEventsLogger.logEvent(name);
   AEMReporterIOS.logAEMEvent(name, 0);
 }
}
```

but I don't see events and I can't connect my device in the event testing tab
maybe I need to set up additional events here [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ySOz.jpg) ?

P.S. on iphone with ios version smaller 14.5 events work normal

Comment: if anyone have same issues you need to separately configure events in facebook event manager -> settings -> and select the necessary events for SKAdNetwork and then select an event for ios 14.5 in the tab below